# mac OSX Lion Homebrew install curl (77)

Tags: homebrew

> curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
>
> > CAfile: /usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bubdle.crt
> >
> > CApath: none

When I tried to download homebrew, I got this error. I have looked at posts with similar errors to this, but none of the fixes for them solved my issue and I have not seen anyone else with this issue on a mac with OSX Lion. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Does it actually say "bubdle" in the error message?

Comment: yes, it does. I'm surprised I didn't see that. How can I fix the CAfile path?

Comment: Does the file  /usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt exist? Which user does own it? CAfile path can be fixed with "export SSL_CERT_FILE=/usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/share/ca-bundle.crt"

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `curl-ca-bundle` does not exist anymore in Homebrew.

I followed the suggest at https://gist.github.com/1stvamp/2158128 which basically does:

```
mkdir /tmp/curl-ca-bundle
cd /tmp/curl-ca-bundle
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.22.0.tar.bz2
tar xzf curl-7.22.0.tar.bz2
cd curl-7.22.0/lib/
```

Check if you the directory `/usr/share/curl` exists.

If so, make a backup of the existing `ca-bundle.crt` file

```
sudo mv /usr/share/curl/ca-bundle.crt /usr/share/curl/ca-bundle.crt.original
```

If not, then create it via: `mkdir /usr/share/curl`.

After, move the ca-bundle.crt file to that directory:

```
sudo mv ca-bundle.crt /usr/share/curl/ca-bundle.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after messing up with my curl, brew, rvm and who knows what else, resulting in completely broken 'pod install' command.

Went to /usr/local/opt/curl and found out that the curl-ca-bundle.crt was created by root user, thus inaccessible to curl running as user. Fixed that with:

```
sudo chmod user:group curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

...and voilá, curl is back. So the (77) error could mean that the CA file is there, but is not readable for some reason.